# nixos Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

Tags: nixos

I installed and now am trying to setup **nixos**.

I installed firefox with

```
$ nix-env -i firefox
```

Now I try to run it but get the following error

```
$ firefox
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

I set the environment variable with `export GDK_BACKEND=X11` but get the same error when attempting to run firefox. Do I need to set the environment variable to something other than `X11`?

**How can I proceed to run firefox and other window-necessary software?**

Comment: Try to run ***export DISPLAY=":0"***, where the 0 is the display Id.